# Changing position of Xpages Dialog Extension

Tags: xpages, lotus

I am using a xpage dialog control to capture review comments.Xpage is designed using mobile controls and i am not able to position the dialog control to top of window. The following example does not alter the position based on the values given in style.

```
<xe:appPage id="IDHomePage" pageName="HomePage" resetContent="true">
  <xe:dialog id="dialog1" style="position:fixed;top:100px;left:25px">
    <xp:table style="container_form_document">
      <xp:tr>
        <xp:td rowspan="2">
           <xe:djSimpleTextarea...................
```

Also a cancel icon (similar to 'X') appears on top of the dialog control which I am not able to get rid of. Any tips?

Comment: I don't think dialog control is intended to work with mobile layout.

Comment: It will work, else we will have to reinvent for the features that require dialog box.I am currently using same for mobile layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the way I have published here.
http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2012/preventing-the-xpages-dialog-control-to-auto-center

Comment: Fredrick, Are you using style property of dialog? If yes, logically it should work for the code what I am using.Am i right?

Comment: I'm using the style property of the dialogbox, so the code should work  for you too